# Two level hierarchy in Python-Django

Tags: python, django, model

I have a problem with the classes design i'm doing.

What i need is to be able to get the last media files that were uploaded through the admin. The media files could be songs, albums, and videos.

So i have the next classes:

```
class MediaFile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Song(models.Model):
    media_data = models.OneToOneField(to=MediaFile) # relation with MediaFile
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='mp3')
    album = models.ManyToManyField(Album)

class Album(models.Model):
    media_data = models.OneToOneField(to=MediaFile) # relation with MediaFile
    cover = models.ImageField(upload_to='albums')
    release_date = models.DateField()

class Video(models.Model):
    media_data = models.OneToOneField(to=MediaFile) # relation with MediaFile
    summary = models.TextField()
```

It is validated ok, but when i run the project, it returns me the next error:

```
<class 'MediaFile'> has no ForeignKey to <class 'Song'>
```

So, do you know what i am doing wrong? Do you know if there is a better way to achieve this? I mean, what i have to achieve is be able to get the last 10 media files uploaded without have to get first rows of songs, then of albums, and then of videos.

I accept critics and suggestions, thanks!

**EDIT:**

The error happen here: **environment\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py in _get_foreign_key, line 942**

**EDIT 2:**

Here is the **Traceback**

```
> Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view

\environment\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in get_response
                    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
\environment\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py in wrapper
                return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
\environment\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py in _wrapped_view
                    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
\environment\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py in _wrapped_view_func
        response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
\environment\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py in inner
            return view(request, *args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
\environment\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py in _wrapper
            return bound_func(*args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
\environment\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py in _wrapped_view
                    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
\environment\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py in bound_func
                return func(self, *args2, **kwargs2) ...
▶ Local vars
\environment\lib\site-packages\django\db\transaction.py in inner
                return func(*args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
\environment\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py in add_view
            for FormSet, inline in zip(self.get_formsets(request), inline_instances): ...
▶ Local vars
\environment\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py in get_formsets
            yield inline.get_formset(request, obj) ...
▶ Local vars
\environment\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py in get_formset
            fields = flatten_fieldsets(self.get_fieldsets(request, obj)) ...
▶ Local vars
\environment\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py in get_fieldsets
        form = self.get_formset(request, obj, fields=None).form ...
▶ Local vars
\environment\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py in get_formset
        return inlineformset_factory(self.parent_model, self.model, **defaults) ...
▶ Local vars
\environment\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py in inlineformset_factory
    fk = _get_foreign_key(parent_model, model, fk_name=fk_name) ...
▶ Local vars
\environment\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py in _get_foreign_key
            raise Exception("%s has no ForeignKey to %s" % (model, parent_model)) ...
▶ Local vars
```

**EDIT 3:**

Here i add the **admin.py**

```
class SongInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Song

class AlbumAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        SongInline,
    ]


class MediaFileInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = MediaFile

class MediaFileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        MediaFileInline,
    ]

admin.site.register(MediaFile)
admin.site.register(Song, MediaFileAdmin)
admin.site.register(Video)
admin.site.register(Album, AlbumAdmin)
```

Comment: What are you doing when you run the project?

Comment: With "running the project" i mean that i do the "runserver" and i enter to the website

Comment: Can you add some more context around what line of code is throwing the error along with the full error message?

Comment: The full error i the one i've added to the description. But checked the edition i've made to the post for the file and line exception.

Comment: Can you either post your full stacktrace or post the last line in it that's referencing a line of code that you wrote?

Comment: @schillingt Check the edit2, i've added the traceback

Comment: Gotcha. I see what you're doing now. Can you add your admin.py file now? It looks like the error is being generated via the admin, so it's likely the problem exists in that file.

Comment: @schillingt Check the edit3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your inline has to be defined for the model that has the OneToOneField defined on it. Below is something you could do.

```
class SongInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Song

class AlbumInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Album

class VideoInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Video

class MediaFileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        SongInline,
        AlbumInline,
        VideoInline
    ]

admin.site.register(MediaFile, MediaFileAdmin)
admin.site.register(Song)
admin.site.register(Video)
admin.site.register(Album)
```

Comment: Ok, it fix the problem but it avoid a feature: i don't want to "select the media file" in the song's admin. I want to edit the fields inline... so how can i use the inline form for the media file model inside the song, video, and album admin?

Comment: If you have a solution i mark your answer as correct

Comment: There isn't a great solution to this. Either you need to change your models so the 1:1 fields are on MediaFile or you can try change the forms that these inlines use.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what's happening is that Django wants a primary key(PK) for integrity reasons with your OneToOneField. Since your model has an implied PK (the auto increment integer kind by default), it's trying to link two things together but hits a wall when it tries to get the objects. In your models try the following:

```
class Song(models.Model):
    media_data = models.OneToOneField(MediaFile, primary_key = True)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='mp3')
    album = models.ManyToManyField(Album)
```

For more information try:
[Django's OneToOne Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/)

Comment: I appreciate this, but i've just tried it and it still not working... another idea?

Comment: @ArielScherman try to add some more of your traceback, it may have to do with your QuerySet or a myriad of other things.

Comment: @ArielScherman Thanks! It looks like you might be trying to reference the MediaFile object instead of a Song that points to a MediaFile object. Hope that helps!